# Optional closing symbol and several words capturing with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, syntax

Is it possible to write a regex formula that can capture more than one word character plus `-` leaded by `#` but if `#` is at the end of several words separated with whitespaces then capture the whole text between the opening and closing `#`?

I belive my code is much easier to understand than my description:

```
import re

s = """
this is a dummy #text with some #dummy_short-tags
and a #full length long tag# that has closing symbol.
"""

print re.findall(r'#([\w-]+)', s)
# --> ['text', 'dummy_short-tags', 'full']
print re.findall(r'#(.+)?(?<!\s)#', s)
# --> ['full length long tag']
```

Can I combine the two regexes above into one? Therefore I can avoid getting "full" and "full length long tag" captured at the same time and also my goal is to treat the captured texts as one type of data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using alternation:

```
re.findall('#([\w\s]+\w(?=#)|[\w-]+)', s)
```

*Output*:

```
['text', 'dummy_short-tags', 'full length long tag']
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much, it is a beautiful regex formula!